# Gmap API V3 marker coordinates

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

I have found example if someone need however I need to get first coordinates from address so later can adjust it. Someone knows how to do it?

`var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {    
  geocoder.geocode({    
    latLng: pos    
  }, function(responses) {  
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {  
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);  
    } else {  
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');  
    }  
  });  
}  

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {  
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;  
}  

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {  
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [  
    latLng.lat(),  
    latLng.lng()  
  ].join(', ');  
}  

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {  
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;  
} 



function initialize() {  


 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.54232,-1.4353423);  

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {  
    zoom: 8,  
    center: latLng,  
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });  

  // Update current position info.  
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);  
  geocodePosition(latLng);  

  // Add dragging event listeners.  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {  
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');  
  });  

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {  
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');    
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());  
  });  

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {  
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');  
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());  
  });  


// Onload handler to fire off the app.  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your browser support the geolocation you want get coordinate with this function :

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      geolocationCoordinates =  new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      //position.coords.latitude = latitude coordonates;
      //position.coords.longitude = longitude coordonates;
    }

after, you can create a new map whith this coordonates.

This code is functional with all browser supporting the geolocation.